# find files in folder newer than

Tags: find

I searched through `man find` but it doesn't give me the answer to a simple task:

**I want to list all files inside a folder that were modified during the last 5 hours.**

I tried

```
find ~/.purple/logs -type f -mmin 1000
```

to show modified files during the last 1000 minutes, but no hits.

Maybe it's my limited english, but what do I have to search for in the manual?

Comment: Try to read `man ls`.

Comment: the same problem ;) I looked for "path" "full" but no solution in man ls

Comment: There are 2 options which can do what you want. `-newer`, and `-mtime`.

Comment: but newer is for "newer than another file", sure I could create a temporary file and compare to that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin -$((60*5)) -type f
```

to list all regular files in the current directory, which were changed during the last 5 hours.

`$((60*5))` is calculated by the shell and therefore equal to 300 min.

Comment: I see, the problem was, that in the manual there is not written that you have to prefix the minutes with a minus

Comment: @rubo77 it's explained in the beginning of the `TESTS` section.

Comment: If you know that there must be a minus, you find various hints in the man page, but not, if you dont expect such thing